# Is there a way of calling a trait method on enum variants that have a field that implements the trait?

Tags: rust

My enum has 40ish variants with about half of them implementing the trait, but here is a simpler example:

```
trait CheeseBoard {
    fn say_cheese(self);
}

struct Cheese {
    name: String,
}

impl CheeseBoard for Cheese {
    fn say_cheese(self) {
        println!("I am {}", self.name);
    }
}

struct Person {
    name: String,
}

impl CheeseBoard for Person {
    fn say_cheese(self) {
        println!("{} says cheese!", self.name);
    }
}

enum CheesyPerson {
    Cheese(Cheese),
    Person(Person),
    UncheesyNonperson,
}

fn main() {
    let _a = [
        CheesyPerson::Cheese(Cheese {
            name: "Gouda".into(),
        }),
        CheesyPerson::Person(Person {
            name: "Peer".into(),
        }),
        CheesyPerson::UncheesyNonperson,
    ];
    todo!("Call say_cheese on items in _a where the enum variant has exactly one field that implements the CheeseBoard trait.")
}
```

Comment: If only half of the variants have a field that implements the trait, what do you do on the other half?

Comment: Are you looking for a `match` statement? `for v in _a { match v { CheesyPerson::Cheese(x) => x.say_cheese(), CheesyPerson::Person(x) => x.say_cheese(), _ => {} } }` ?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think the OP wants to avoid the boilerplate of listing all variants.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman perhaps! However, the OP *hasn't said that explicitly*, and I've been yelled at by too many SO posters when I try to assume what they mean and get it wrong somehow.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this in Rust without, say, writing a macro that will just write the code for you.

Comment: I ended up doing the boilerplate listing thingy that I was trying to avoid. It's probably not the best way to do things, and trying to implement dmx-512/rdm in rust with everything nicely enumerated and #[no_std], as is what I'm trying to do; might not be the best idea. But after 4000 lines of code, maybe I'll learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly possible in Rust; it has no mechanism to even match on "any enum possibility that has a single value," let alone that implements a particular trait.

The cleanest way I can think of to implement this is with a helper method that gives back a `Option<&dyn CheeseBoard>`:

```
impl CheesyPerson {
    fn get_cheese_board(&self) -> Option<&dyn CheeseBoard> {
        match self {
            Self::Cheese(v) => Some(v),
            Self::Person(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
for v in _a.iter().filter_map(|v| v.get_cheese_board()) {
    v.say_cheese();
}
```

Note this requires changing your `CheeseBoard::say_cheese` method because right now it takes `self` by value, consuming the `CheeseBoard` in the process.  The method needs to take `self` by reference.

```
trait CheeseBoard {
    fn say_cheese(&self);
    //            ^
    // Add this to take self by reference
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5cb4457d365fbbdacc49dde28dcf0c98))

Answer (score 0):

Thank @cdhowie, your comment saves me from another hours of torment!

In case anyone wraps the enum with another layer of struct, ensure that you *borrow* the enum, not copy it. For example,

```rust
struct RoomForOne(CheesyPerson);

impl RoomForOne {
    fn get_cheese_board(&self) -> Option<&dyn CheeseBoard> {
        match &self.0 { // & here is important!
            CheesyPerson::Cheese(v) => Some(v),
            CheesyPerson::Person(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```